# Meaning and grammatical category of "Luftnummer"?

Tags: grammar, verb, noun, meaning-in-context

> [Opposition wirft Friedrich "Luftnummer" vor](http://www.zeit.de/digital/datenschutz/2013-07/friedrich-usa-opposition).

*wirft ... vor* is, I think, the verb *vorwerfen*, which means *to accuse*.

But I don't know what *Luftnummer* means. Is it a noun in this context? I'm asking this because on [www.leo.de](http://dict.leo.org/?lang=de&lp=ende#/search=luftnummer&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on) this word is only registered as a verb; this one: *to turn out to be a flop*.

Comment: a minor thing but vorwerfen would be "to accuse of"... vorwerfen is super-transitive with the deed being the direct object while accuse has the accused as direct object. That is quite a difference.

Comment: I see. Good to know. Danke!

Comment: *Nummer* as in *Luftnummer* originally referred to a numbered act in a *Nummernrevue (vaudeville revue)*. Presumably, a Luftnummer ('air act') was one that required only air rather than singers, dancers, comedians, animals etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *Luftnummer* may be a *flop,* but most likely it is something that turns out to be *nothing but hot air.* Some typical examples:

- A new law that is supposed to prevent something bad, but entirely fails to do so, because it can easily be circumvented.
- A promise that has never been intedended to be kept in the first place.
- A venture that does nothing but draining money from its investors.
- Something that is claimed to be a success but actually was a total failure.

Note that in the example you quoted, the quotation marks are actually wrong, since they imply that the opposition already used the term *Luftnummer* with quotes (*vorwerfen* already establishes that *Luftnummer* does not necessarily reflect the opinion of the author, so there are no quotes needed for this purpose).

Also note that Leo does not give *to turn out to be a flop* as a translation for *Luftnummer* but for *sich als Luftnummer erweisen,* which is a verb.

Comment: I strongly disagree with your aside about the quotation marks; I even downvoted the whole answer for it. They are not at all wrong, and their presence or absence changes the information in the text. If the quotation marks are there, the author asserts that the opposition used the exact term _Luftnummer_. If they aren’t, it could be the author’s paraphrase of the opposition’s viewpoint; their representative might have said _Friedrich macht doch nur viel Wirbel um nichts_ or similar.

Comment: *Vorwerfen* already states that this is reported speech and paraphrasing in such a situation would be bad journalism and could (in a slightly different situation) lead to accusations of slander. If, e.g., *Luftnummer* were replaced with *Versagen* or *Betrug,* would you still use quotes? And if yes, what would be your opinion on a journalist who paraphrases to *Betrug* in a corresponding situation (not using quotes)? By the way, there is an [intensive discussion](http://www.belleslettres.eu/artikel/gansefusschen-anfuhrungszeichen.php#falsche-direkte-rede-im-bericht) of this on Belles Lettres.

Comment: OK. So how could this thing actually be translated into English? I'm still confused...

Comment: @indoxica: _Opposition accuses Mr Friedrich of doing busy work_, _… of producing only hot air_?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: _Vorwerfen_ gehört nicht zu den Meta-Wörtern wie _sprechen von_, _bezeichnen als_, _nennen_, _sogenannt_. Daß Zitate „nicht als Frag­mente in den eigenen Fließ­text mon­tiert“ werden sollten (hier bewußt mißachtet :)), mag ein guter Ratschlag sein, aber von _weniger elegant_ zu _falsch_ ist es noch ein arger Sprung.